# Is it possible to write PHPDoc documentation for @param without specifying the type?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm using PhpStorm. When I put the following PHPDoc documentation for a function:

```php
/**
 * @param $id application identifier
 */
public function foo($id)
```

And I run the "Quick documentation" (Ctrl + Q) command for the function in PHPStorm, it shows this:

> Parameters: [App\Models\Application](https://example.com/placeholder_url) **$id** identifier

It looks like for some reason, the IDE is interpreting the first word of the parameter description, `application`, as the type for the parameter. I don't want to specify the type of the parameter (I don't know what it is), I just want to add a brief description about the parameter in the documentation. What should I do?

Comment: Use `mixed` type (or some other generic) then. PHPDoc requires type. In your case, IDE treats it as PHPDoc-like syntax where type goes after the name.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what it is, you can use `mixed`. The type goes before the `$id` and the part after `$id` will be used as the description.

```
/**
 * @param mixed $id application identifier
 */
public function foo($id)
```